# Why would a question not appear in "Leave Open" Review queue?

Tags: support, closing-questions, vote-to-reopen, review-queue

I wanted to vote to "Leave Open" for this question: [What would have happened if a younger student had gotten his name in the Goblet of Fire?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32338/what-would-have-happened-if-a-younger-student-had-gotten-his-name-in-the-goblet) , but couldn't find it in the Review Queue anymore.

**Why was it not in the LO Review Queue?**

1. Is that because too many people - 3 already voted to leave it open?
2. Or because 5 people total reviewed?
3. Or because # of Leave Open votes balanced # of Close votes (3 each)?
4. Or time cutoff?
5. Other?

Here's the review history for it:

```
Beofett       Q  Leave Open 30 mins ago
phantom42     Q  Leave Open 2 hours ago
NikolaiDante  Q  Close  7 hours ago
Jack B Nimble Q  Close  10 hours ago
John O        Q  Leave Open 10 hours ago
```

I'm suspecting #3.

Comment: One possibility is that maybe it doesn't show up in the queue if you already viewed the question outside of the queue. I had a similar situation with another question, where I saw that it had garnered several close votes, went to the close review queue, and only saw the question you listed (which is how I wound up reviewing it). [That question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32305/what-is-this-missing-part-to-the-tron-legacy-soundtrack) has 3 "leave open" votes, and 4 close votes, which makes your #3 seem less likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a question gets 3 "Leave Open" votes, it is removed from the review queue.  Keep in mind that LO votes don't actually affect the question's closure*, just its queue status.

*: with the minor exception that [being booted from the queue by LO votes begins the CV aging timer even if the question did not have the 100 views normally necessary for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166124/172958).

Comment: Actually, I think they do affect the expiration of closure votes, but my memory is hazy.

Comment: Possibly expiration, I'll ask, but they don't cancel them or raise the threshold

Comment: Correct on that last 2.

Comment: After asking and searching on MSO, the only effect I can find is that once the question gets booted from the queue the votes start aging even if it had <100 views. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166124/172958)