# Why doesn't this question show up in the review queue for Close Votes?

Tags: support, closing-questions, review-queue

The following question has, as I'm writing this, 1 close vote against it.<sup>‡</sup>

[How do the pirate tests in Uncharted 4 get reset?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/145335/19561)

[image: Question about Uncharted 4 with a close vote against it]

There is a discussion about it in the comments and I disagree with the close vote, so I'd like to vote to leave open. So I went to [the review queue for close votes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close), but I didn't see it there.

[image: The review close votes queue, empty]

So I went to the [close vote review history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/history), but it wasn't in there either.

[image: The review close votes history]

**Why doesn't the question show up in the close votes review queue for me?**

---

There is a similar question here on meta, but there the reason was there were already 3 votes to leave open for it.

[Why would a question not appear in "Leave Open" Review queue?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2752/19561)

---

<sub>*‡: since I've started this question, the close vote has been retracted.*</sub>

Comment: I can’t be sure, but could it just have been delayed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The vote wasn’t there long enough

As discussed on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284734/328832):

> The default delay is… 15 minutes. **No review tasks for the Close or
>   Reopen queues will be created until the oldest pending close vote or
>   flag or reopen vote or qualifying edit is at least 15 minutes old.** No
>   review tasks for the Late Answer or Low Quality review queues will be
>   created until the post itself is at least 15 minutes old.

So the close vote didn’t have time to hit the 15  minute mark, since the user who cast it (me), withdrew it before then.

[image: A bit of the timeline, showing the close vote and its retraction]

Comment: This is confirmed by the post's timeline: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTYRv.png (not sure exactly how much of the timeline is visible to non-mods)

Comment: @Randal'Thor if that's from the post's timeline at [http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/145335/timeline](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/145335/timeline) then no, the close vote isn't visible to mere mortals. So it was _close_ to 15 minutes, but not quite there yet.