# Question with close votes, is not in the close vote review queue even after 15 minutes

Tags: support

According to [Why doesn't this question show up in the review queue for Close Votes?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10346/why-doesnt-this-question-show-up-in-the-review-queue-for-close-votes), questions with close votes should show up in the close vote review queue 15 minutes after "the oldest pending close vote or flag or reopen vote or qualifying edit is at least 15 minutes old".

I am looking at a question that has had 1 pending close vote for more than 15 minutes, but I do not see it in the close vote review queue. I have had no interaction with the question, so I don't think it is just me that doesn't see it.

I would prefer not to unleash the meta effect on the question, so before I link to it, is the answer to the meta question I linked to above accurate? Can anyone suggest a reason why a question that had a vote to close more than 15 minutes ago would not be in the review queue?

[Edit] The question is [Why did the show's producers choose to base their Klingons on Americans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170374/why-did-the-shows-producers-choose-to-base-their-klingons-on-americans). At the moment, it still has one close vote (Unclear what you're asking), and I still don't see it on the close vote review queue.

Comment: If there was a 'leave open' by a mod that would immediately remove it from the queue, but aside from that, I'm stumped.

Comment: @Mithrandir Thanks. I have added to a link to the question.

Comment: Well, that makes things easier :) - it's easier to check a specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It *did* go through the queue.

Scrolling through the [list of all reviews that 10kers can see](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/history), I can see an item in there:

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/113624

The question in question did go through the close vote queue on September 25, and got three 'Leave Open' votes, one by a site moderator, and so was removed from the queue.

[image]

Comment: Oh bloody hell I got FGIW'd on Meta. An image would help your case

Comment: @Edlothiad - screenshot added ;)

Comment: Fair enough, but if the mod's Leave Open vote settles the matter, shouldn't the outstanding close vote be cleared?

Comment: @Blackwood - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166124/294691

Comment: I still think it is confusing to just wait for close votes to age away if voting is considered complete, but thanks for providing the answer to the question.

Comment: It's now more than 4 days since the Leave Open votes shown in you screen shot, and the answer still shows 1 close vote. The post you linked to suggests it should have aged away by now. Am I missing something.